# UPDATE table row with SELECT and GROUP_CONCAT function in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have 3 tables in my sql database.

This is my tables with a data:

```
table1
ID         WORD
1          a
2          b
3          c
7          o
14         z
32         q
57         i

table2
ID         FORWORD
1          apple
1          orange
3          disc1
3          disc2
3          disc3
14         book
32         letter1
32         letter2
32         letter3
57         keyboard
57         mouse

table3
ROWID      WORD       NAME
1          a          NULL
2          b          NULL
3          c          NULL
4          o          example, example1
5          z          NULL
6          q          window, window1
7          i          NULL
```

table1 and table2 have the same ID. table1 and table3 have the WORD. 
I want to update data in column NAME in table3 and get result as below:

```
table3
ROWID      WORD       NAME
1          a          apple, orange
2          b          NULL
3          c          disc1, disc2, disc3
4          o          NULL
5          z          book
6          q          letter1, letter2, letter3
7          i          mouse
```

Please, help to solve that issue.

Comment: What's your question here? What query have you tried that didn't work and where *exactly* are you stuck? Unless I'm missing something, this should be very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`, using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
update table3 t3
  join (
    select t1.word, group_concat(t2.forward order by t2.forward separator ', ') name
    from table1 t1
      left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    group by t1.word
    ) t on t3.word = t.word
set t3.name = t.name;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b1b4/2)

Please note, row 7 should return keyboard, mouse as table2 has 2 records with 57.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: thank you. But what is the t3, t2, t1, t? it gives an error: "near t3 : syntax error"

Comment: @YoungDeveloper -- those are just table aliases -- shorthand for the full table name.  Did you review the SQL Fiddle?  Can you post your query/sample data with the error?

Comment: I have executed the same query that you have answered. Is it possible to make query without t,t1,t2,t3? Yes, I have viewed SQL Fiddle, I'm using sqlite, is it a problem?